# How can I use multiple toggle on one page JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, toggle

How can use multiple toggle on one page?
I have two div in my HTML file and I want to hide or remove the `child-1` div and then replace with another div `child-2` when every time that clicking on parent title.
my HTML structure as below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.child_1').show();
  $('.child_2').hide();

  $('.parent').click( function() {
 $(this).each( function() {
   $('.child_1, .child_2').toggle();
 });
  });
});
```

```css
.child_1, .child_2 {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent"> 
 <h2>Title One</h2>
 <div class='child_1'>paragraph 1</div>
 <div class='child_2'>paragraph 2</div>
</div>
   
<div class="parent"> 
 <h2>Title Two</h2>
 <div class='child_1'>paragraph 1</div>
 <div class='child_2'>paragraph 2</div>
</div>
```

This work perfectly but when I click in one element other element also change.

Please see here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mojtaba_Reyhani/cc3bmxx8/11/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change your js function slightly:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('.child_1').show();
$('.child_2').hide();

$('.parent').click( function() {
$(this).each( function() {
  $('.child_1, .child_2',this).toggle();
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent"> 
 <h2>Title One</h2>
 <div class='child_1'>paragraph 1</div>
 <div class='child_2'>paragraph 2</div>
</div>
      
<div class="parent"> 
 <h2>Title Two</h2>
 <div class='child_1'>paragraph 1</div>
 <div class='child_2'>paragraph 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and replay. I appreciate you sincerely, your answer helped me a lot.

Comment: Great Solution,and best possible answer, Right, Accurate and Perfect, Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 1):

#### Bug in your code:

The following code calls `.toggle()` on every instance of `$('parent')` thus applying the `.click()` logic to all `.parent` elements rather than just the clicked one:

```
$('.parent').click( function() {
    $(this).each( function() {
      $('.child_1, .child_2').toggle();
    });
  });
```

In order to fix this problem one could rewrite it as follows:

```
  $('.parent').click( function() {
    $(this).children('div').toggle('.child_1, .child_2');
  });
```

---

#### Suggested approach:

The best way to approach this is by using [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) on the `.parent` element when clicked.

The class when present will dictate the state of specified children - when class `show` is active on `.parent` show `.child_2` and when not show `child_1`. This way you set one state as the *initial* view avoiding the need to [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) it on load.

It's best practice to control visual states with [css](/questions/tagged/css) when possible (i.e. class with `display: none` and/or `display: block`) and dictating the styles of contained elements based on the parent element's state/class.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.parent').click( function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('show');    
    });
});
```

```css
.child_1, .show .child_2 {
  display: block;
}
.child_2, .show .child_1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent"> 
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div class='child_1'>paragraph 1</div>
  <div class='child_2'>paragraph 2</div>
</div>
  
<div class="parent"> 
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div class='child_1'>paragraph 1</div>
  <div class='child_2'>paragraph 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That problem arise form my bad post editing and not relevant to own code, I edit my question, Please update your post. Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just toggle the div children.

```
$(function(){ 
  $('.parent').click( function() {
    $(this).children("div").toggle();
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jakecigar/cc3bmxx8/18/ <--